# Delete decimals of a specific columns with sed

Tags: awk, sed, replace, decimal, truncate

I am working with a csv file and I want to truncate the numbers with decimals of a specific column.
Three of the lines are:

123;rr;2;RRyO, chess mobil;pio;**25.766**;1;0;24353;21.876;;S

1243;rho;9;RpO, chess yext cat;downpio;**67.98**;1;0;237753;25.346;;S

1243;rho;9;RpO, chess yext cat;pio;**73**;1;0;237753;25.346;;S

And I want this output:

123;rr;2;RRyO, chess mobil;pio;**25**;1;0;24353;21.876;;S

1243;rho;9;RpO, chess yext cat;downpio;**67**;1;0;237753;25.346;;S

1243;rho;9;RpO, chess yext cat;pio;**73**;1;0;237753;25.346;;S

I have tried thies code:

```
sed  -e '/^.\+pio$/,/^\..\*;[[:digit:]];[[:digit:]];.\*;.\*;.\*;.\*[[:space:]]$/d' data.csv
```

but doesnt work...
Any suggestion, please?

Comment: `sed -E 's/^(([^;]*;){5}[0-9]*)[^;]*/\1/' data.csv` might do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/^\(\([^;]*;\)\{5\}[0-9]*\)[^;]*/\1/' data.csv
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\(\([^;]*;\)\{5\}[0-9]*\)` - Group 1 (`\1`):

  - `\([^;]*;\)\{5\}` - five occurrences of any zero or more chars other than `;` and a `;`
  - `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `[^;]*` - zero or more chars other than `;`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/XZtOey):

```sh
s='123;rr;2;RRyO, chess mobil;pio;25.766;1;0;24353;21.876;;S
1243;rho;9;RpO, chess yext cat;downpio;67.98;1;0;237753;25.346;;S
1243;rho;9;RpO, chess yext cat;pio;73;1;0;237753;25.346;;S'
sed 's/^\(\([^;]*;\)\{5\}[0-9]*\)[^;]*/\1/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```sh
123;rr;2;RRyO, chess mobil;pio;25;1;0;24353;21.876;;S
1243;rho;9;RpO, chess yext cat;downpio;67;1;0;237753;25.346;;S
1243;rho;9;RpO, chess yext cat;pio;73;1;0;237753;25.346;;S
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following. You could simple convert floating points to digits by `awk`'s sprintf function.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$6=sprintf("%d",$6)} 1' Input_file
```

From man page of `awk`:

> sprintf(fmt, expr-list) Print expr-list according to fmt, and return
> the resulting string.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't fully reverse-engineered you sed command, but this seems to work:

```
sed 's/\(.*pio;[0-9]*\)\.[0-9]*/\1/' data.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?|([^;]+)/\1\3/6' file
```

Fields may be numbers, numbers with a decimal or not numbers.

On the sixth such field return the number part only if it exists.